# Lookup component in flow does not save the record in salesforce

Tags: lightning, lightning-flow-builder

I've came across an issue related to Lookup in flow builder. Inside Contact Request Flow I've tried to add another component (lookup). When I run it, it shows me related lookup records but when I check it inside a Salesforce it's not saved there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you assign the result of the lookup request to the lookup field in the object you are saving?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to do that :/. Can you send me some help text?
Thanks :)

Comment: You need to use Edit and update your post with the Flow